# Pandas - Read time with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I need to read a csv file in which a column stores times of the day in HH:MM:SS format. I need to make comparisons with these times so my idea is to use datetime. The date information is not relevant nor present in the file.

If I read the file and parse the date like this:

```
import pandas as pd    
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')
my_data = pd.read_csv(file_name, parse_dates=['Time'], date_parser=dateparse)
print(my_data.loc[0]['Time'])
```

I get 1900-01-01 11:03:41. How do I get rid of the date and year? I do not need it and will not need it in my output file.
Is there a way to read this column to datetime.time format?

I also tried:

```
my_data = pd.read_csv(file_name, parse_dates=['Time'], 
                     date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H:%M:%S'))
```

with the same result.

Comment: The deleted answer showed that you could do this using `dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S').time()` or `pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H:%M:%S').time()` but like I said this has performance issues, personally I wouldn't store non-numpy native dtypes in a df unless you just want the `pandas` convenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to modify the output to a csv you can specify the `date_format` in `to_csv`:

```
In[130]:    
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[pd.datetime.strptime('11:03:41', '%H:%M:%S')]})
df.to_csv(date_format='%H:%M:%S')

Out[130]: ',date\n0,11:03:41\n'
```

I would advise to keep your data as `datetime64` because it allows you to perform vectorised arithmetic on the column, if you store as `datetime.time` objects then it limits what you can do

You can always just add an additional column either as the `datetime.time` or a `str` representation:

```
In[131]:
df['time'] = df['date'].dt.time
df['str_rep'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df

Out[131]: 
                 date      time   str_rep
0 1900-01-01 11:03:41  11:03:41  11:03:41
```

To demonstrate my point:

```
In[136]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['11:03:41', '15:23:33'], format='%H:%M:%S').time})
df
Out[136]: 
       date
0  11:03:41
1  15:23:33
```

now if we perform arithmetic:

```
df['date'].diff()
```

this will raise:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

whilst if we keep the `dtype` as `datetime64` we can still perform arithmetic and comparisons, as the dates are all the same they cancel out anyway depending on what you're doing:

```
In[138]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['11:03:41', '15:23:33'], format='%H:%M:%S')})
df

Out[138]: 
                 date
0 1900-01-01 11:03:41
1 1900-01-01 15:23:33

In[139]:
df.diff()

Out[139]: 
      date
0      NaT
1 04:19:52
```

**update**

If you really want `datetime.time` then you could modify your `lambda`:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S').time()
my_data = pd.read_csv(file_name, parse_dates=['Time'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

or this would also work:

```
my_data = pd.read_csv(file_name, parse_dates=['Time'], 
                     date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H:%M:%S').time())
```

comparisons and some arithmetic operations will work but it's not as flexible as the native `datetime64` dtype.

Comment: Can I compare times in datetime64 format as I would do with datetime?

Comment: sure it will just work because all dates are the same then any relativedelta or differences will just use the time component

Comment: The problem is I have to compare these times with times from another source. It is quite uncomfortable to then deal with a time carrying the 1st Jan 1900 information.... as the other times surely will not have it.

Comment: As I've shown you can call `dt.time` on the constructed `datetime` column to generate a `time` only column but comparison and operations are probably not vectorised

Comment: I eventually created an extra column with time datetime.time format and deleted it before writing the data to the output file. I still wonder if and how it's possible to read the time with read_csv directly in datetime.time format. Anyway this solved my problem so accepted answer, thanks

Comment: As I said you could amend your lambda `dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S').time()` this will import as `datetime.time` objects